# How to join/fill null values using second table while keeping other values intact?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I fill the null values in Table A using values from Table B while keeping all other columns/rows intact?

Table A

| name | dept | job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jon | **null** | analyst |
| mary | **null** | supervisor |
| lucy | **null** | actuary |
| mark | retail | manager |
| cindy | retail | sales |

Table B

| name | dept | job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jon | hr | null |
| mary | hr | null |
| lucy | finance | null |

attempts to use joins has incorrect results due to having to select which columns show in final table.  ex:

```
SELECT a.name, b.dept, a.job
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b
ON a.name=b.name
```

will show

| name | dept | job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jon | hr | analyst |
| mary | hr | supervisor |
| lucy | finance | actuary |
| mark | **null** | manager |
| cindy | **null** | sales |

I've tried out different types of joins, but can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COALESCE()` to combine two values that could be null.

For example:

```
SELECT a.name,
  coalesce(a.dept, b.dept) as dept, 
  coalesce(a.job, b.job) as job
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b
ON a.name=b.name
```